# Connecting HIVE from Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I have installed Hadoop-3.3.0 and Hive-3.1.2 in Ubuntu WSL (as windows subsystem).
I have all hadoop, YARN and hiveserver2 demons running in Ubuntu WSL.

In my windows OS (host), I open Scala IDE. Via Spark/Scala, I would like to connect to HIVE tables which are available in Ubuntu WSL.

In Windows, I have nothing related to Hadoop/HIVE installed. Everything is available only in Ubuntu WSL.

Can someone please help how to do this in Scala IDE.

I do this with Maven.

Code I use:

```
 val spark =  SparkSession
             .builder
             .master("local[*]")
             .appName("My APP")
             .config("spark.sql.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083") 
             .enableHiveSupport() 
             .getOrCreate 

spark.sql("show tables").show();
```

Error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate SparkSession with Hive support because Hive classes are not found.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.enableHiveSupport
```

Thanks!

Comment: provide the correct path to your hive tables inside WSL. See https://superuser.com/questions/1067373/where-is-the-linux-subsystems-filesystem-located-in-windows-10 and https://superuser.com/questions/1185033/what-is-the-home-directory-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux

Comment: Hi Mike, sorry not getting you. Actually my hive and hadoop demons are running in WSL. I have scala IDE opened in windows and want to connect to HIVE running on WSL.

Comment: In the scala IDE, connect to hive by reading the hive table from the appropriate path - does that give any error?

Comment: yes, I am actually getting an error. I have given the code and error in the question now.